# Character Encoding Issues, Unable to decode HTML entities using PERL APIs

Tags: perl, html-entities, decoding

I am going nuts with the Encoding schemes now. I will state my problem below, please give your inputs.

Problem : I have some input string as mentioned in code below. The final desired output is "Křižovnická 190".[ You can decode it [here](http://htmlentities.net/) ]. I am using perl modules to decode these kind of strings. Following is my test code :

```
use HTML::Entities;
binmode STDOUT,":utf8";
$a = "K&#345;i&#158;ovnick&aacute; 190";
decode_entities($a);
print $a."\n";
```

However the output, I am getting is "Křiovnická 19" which means that "ř" is decoded properly, but "ž" is not. My question is WHY? I then tried "_decode_entities" method where we supply entity2char hash, but still no success.

PS : I am bound to use Perl here, because of other legacy APIs, please help me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#158;` does not refer to "ž". it's [U+009E PRIVACY MESSAGE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9e/index.htm), a control character. (158<sub>10</sub> = 9E<sub>16</sub>)

"ž" is [U+017E LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17e/index.htm), so the escape would be `&#x017E;` or `&#382;`.

Some web browsers interpret numerical entities with a of value in 80..9F<sub>16</sub> (128..159<sub>10</sub>) incorrectly, treating the number as the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding of the Unicode code point.

```
| Grapheme           |         ř         |         ž         |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Unicode Code Point | U+0159 (345)      | U+017E (382)      |
| Escape             | &#x0159; (&#345;) | &#x017E; (&#382;) |
+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| cp1252 encoding    | ---               | 9E (158)          |
| Alternate escape*  | ---               | &#x9E; (&#158;)   |

* — Non-standard and buggy behaviour.
```

This buggy behaviour is the one you desire. I don't see a module implementing that behaviour, so we'll have to code our own.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use HTML::Entities qw( );
use Encode         qw( decode );

{
    my %fixes =
        map { chr($_) => decode('cp1252', chr($_)) }
          0x80..0x9F;

    sub decode_entities {
        my $s_ref = defined(wantarray())
            ? do { my ($s) = @_; \$s }
            : \$_[0];

        $$s_ref =~ s{(
            &\#
            (?: 0*([1-9][0-9]*);?
            |   x0*([1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]*);?
            )
        )}{
            if (defined($2) && length($2) == 3 && exists($fixes{chr($2)})) {
               $fixes{chr($2)}
            } elsif (defined($3) && length($3) == 2 && exists($fixes{chr(hex($3))})) {
               $fixes{chr(hex($3))}
            } else {
               $1
            }
        }exg;

        HTML::Entities::decode_entities($$s_ref);
        return $$s_ref;        
    }
}

print(decode_entities("K&#345;i&#158;ovnick&aacute; 190"), "\n");
```

Answer (score 7):

The character "ž" corresponds to `&#382;` in Unicode, not `&#158;`. 158 is the encoding of "ž" in cp1252.

BTW, Clementinum is nice.

For clarity:

```
| Grapheme   |         ř         |         ž         |
|------------+-------------------+-------------------|
| Codepoint  | U+0159 (345)      | U+017E (382)      |
| Escape     | &#x0159; (&#345;) | &#x017E; (&#382;) |
|------------+-------------------+-------------------|
| UTF-8      | C5 99 (197 153)   | C5 BE (197 190)   | 
| cp1252     | -                 | 9E    (158)       |
| latin2     | F8    (248)       | BE    (190)       |
```

### Update:

See [HTML Decimal Character Rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_decimal_character_rendering) at Wikipedia for details. The important part is:

> (...) references to characters 128–159 are commonly interpreted by lenient web browsers as if they were references to the characters assigned to bytes 128–159 (decimal) in the Windows-1252 character encoding. This is in violation of HTML and SGML standards, and the characters are already assigned to higher code points, so HTML document authors should always use the higher code points. For example, for the trademark sign (™), use `&#8482;`, not `&#153;`.

Comment: But Choroba, the actial string is "Křižovnická 190" and the legacy system has stored "ž" as &#158 which I guess is latin encoding. How do I decode it back to original string is my concern

Comment: On htmlentities.com &#158 as well as &#382 give same character. Why is there duplicate code for same character

Comment: The legacy system uses utf-8 encoding of `ř` and cp1250 encoding of `ž`. Latin-2 (or iso-8859-2) for `ř` and `ž` is 248 and 190, respectively.

Comment: There was major confusion between Unicode code points and UTF-8. Fixed.

Comment: cp1250 and iso-latin-2 are irrelevant, it's cp1252 that matters.

Comment: @ikegami: "ř" does not exist in cp1252.

Comment: cp1250 is irrelevat, true. latin was mentioned by the OP, the only latin containing ř and ž is latin2.